# satelliteLib-5ef5c3c….js:2 SATELLITE: TypeError - Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, adobe-analytics

I am using Adobe analytics for Angularjs SPA application. I see the following response along with an error :

> **SATELLITE: TypeError - Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined**

**Console window details:**

```
SATELLITE: detected tabblur on #document
satelliteLib-5ef5c3c….js:2 SATELLITE: Direct call Rule "new-page-view" fired.
app.js:186 PageName :article : testarticle
app.js:187 ContentType :article
app.js:188 contentID :3726
app.js:189 ContentTitle :testarticle
app.js:190 ContentCountry :Australia
app.js:191 ContentYear :2016
app.js:192 PrimaryCategory :News Feed
app.js:193 SecondaryCategory :abcd
satelliteLib-5ef5c3c….js:2 SATELLITE: Direct call Rule "new-page-view" fired.
satelliteLib-5ef5c3c….js:2 SATELLITE: Direct call Rule "clearVars-dcr" fired.
satelliteLib-5ef5c3c….js:2 SATELLITE: clearing variables...
satelliteLib-5ef5c3c….js:2 SATELLITE: Direct call Rule "clearVars-dcr" fired.
satelliteLib-5ef5c3c….js:2 SATELLITE: clearing variables...
satelliteLib-5ef5c3c….js:2 SATELLITE: Variables cleared
satelliteLib-5ef5c3c….js:2 SATELLITE: Direct call Rule "cleared-page-view" fired.
satelliteLib-5ef5c3c….js:2 SATELLITE: TypeError - Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined
```

From the console I see the error source is from the satelliteLib-5ef5c3c….js file. This is working fine in higher environment but not in my local development environment.
Can anyone provide their guidance here to fix this issue.

Comment: You're going to have to show the content of the direct call rule that caused it.

Answer (score 1):

There's going to be some custom code within the 'cleared-page-view' direct call rule that is giving you the error. I suspect that the method is being used on a variable that's not a string.

If you're able to provide the content within the direct call rule, we can be a bit more specific.